# Find list of topper across each class when given individual scores for each subject

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I need help in writing an efficient query to find a list of toppers (students with maximum total marks in each class) when we are given individual scores for each subject across different classes. We are required to return 3 columns: class, topper_student name and topper_student_total marks.

I have used multiple sub-queries to find a solution. I am sure there would be much better implementations available for this problem (maybe via joins or window functions?).

Input table and my solution can be found at SQL Fiddle link.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2919e/1/0

Input table:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be clearer to use temporary tables to store results along the way and make the result traceable, but the solution can be achieved with a single query:

```
WITH student_marks AS (
    SELECT Class_num, Name, SUM(Marks) AS student_total_marks
    FROM School
    GROUP BY Class_num, Name
) 
SELECT Class_num, Name, student_total_marks 
FROM ( 
    SELECT Class_num, Name, student_total_marks, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by Class_num order by student_total_marks desc, Class_num) AS beststudentfirst
    FROM student_marks
) A
WHERE A.beststudentfirst = 1
```

The query within WITH statement calculate a sum of marks for every student in a class. At this point, **subject** is not required anymore. The result is temporarily stored into **student_marks**.

Next, we need to create a counter (beststudentfirst) using ROW_NUMBER to number the total marks from the highest to the lowest in each class (order by student_total_marks desc, Class_num). The counter should be reinitiated each time the class changes (partition by Class_num order).

From this last result, we only need the counter (beststudentfirst) with the value of one. It is the top student in each class.

Answer (score 0):

Window functions are the most natural way to approach this.  If you always want exactly three students, then use `row_number()`:

```
select Class_num, Name, total_marks
from (select name, class_num, sum(marks) as total_marks,
             row_number() over (partition by class_num order by sum(marks) desc) as seqnum
      from School
      group by Class_num, Name
     ) s
where seqnum <= 1
order by class_num, total_marks desc;
```

If you want to take ties into account, then use `rank()` or `dense_rank()`.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2919e/3) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I get the desired answer using your query only if I make  ``` where seqnum = 1``` change.

Comment: @ShadabAzeem . . . Funny.  I misread the "3" in the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
select Class_num,[Name],total_marks from
(
select Row_number() over (partition by class_num order by Class_num,SUM(Marks) desc) as 
[RN],Class_num,[Name],SUM(Marks) as total_marks
from School
group by Class_num,[Name]
)A
where RN=1
```

Comment: Can you explain why/how this works, so other people can understand?

Comment: The inner query will get all the students sum marks. Then I have partitioned the data on basis of class number and ordered it by sum of marks(descending). Now, to get the maximum marks in each class we just have to filter the rownumber 1